# snd function with a triple

Tags: haskell, tuples

When using the snd function on a pair it works fine i.e.

```
snd (1,2) ~> 2
```

But it does not work in a triple i.e.

```
snd (1,2,3) ~>

<interactive>:2:5:
Couldn't match expected type `(a0, b0)'
            with actual type `(t0, t1, t2)'
In the first argument of `snd', namely `(1, 2, 3)'
In the expression: snd (1, 2, 3)
In an equation for `it': it = snd (1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the type of `snd` function is like this:

```
snd :: (a, b) -> b
```

It will only work on tuples. (single pair elements.)

If you want something like that to work on triples, you have to create your own:

```
extractThird :: (a, b, c) -> c
extractThird (_, _, a) = a
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [`lens`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) mentioned by kqr, there's a slightly simpler package [`tuple`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tuple) which has tons of utility functions for different sized tuples. For example, the module [`Data.Tuple.Select`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tuple-0.2.0.1/docs/Data-Tuple-Select.html) has `sel1` and `sel2` which correspond to `fst` and `snd` but work for 2-15 element tuples.

```
> sel2 (1,2,3)
2

> sel2 (1,2)
2

> sel2 ("a", "b", "c", "d", "e)
"b"
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `fst` and `snd` are only defined for pairs.

```
λ: :t snd
snd :: (a, b) -> b
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more general function to extract elements from tuples, you can do the same thing with the [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-3.9.0.2) library.

```
λ> view _1 ("lens", "gives", "you", "general", "things")
"lens"
λ> view _2 ("lens", "gives", "you", "general", "things")
"gives"
λ> view _3 ("lens", "gives", "you", "general", "things")
"you"
```

and so on. Lens provides very powerful functions for peering into data structures (including tuples) and picking out values from them or modifying them.